# QueryItems azure-cosmos package

Tags: python, pandas, azure, dataframe, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to query a cosmos db and store a table into a pandas data frame (or just as a list, the problem is the same), using the following code

```
table_link= 'dbs/'+database_name+'/colls/'+container_name
query= 'SELECT * FROM '+container_name
df=pd.DataFrame(client.QueryItems(table_link,query,
                              {'enableCrossPartitionQuery': True}))
```

but I have two problems with the output (see the image attached).

[image: output data]

First, I have extra columns id, $pk, &id....that shouldn't be there (I could just ask for the columns that I want in the query, but I have several tables and that would mean to write a different one for each one of them). And second, for the actual columns of the table, I get a dict with two keys "t" and "v" beign v the real value of that field.

Any help? I'm not sure if this is the expected behaviour of QueryItems, but I don't see any way to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the `Target API` for your Cosmos DB account. More than likely it is `Table API`. If the API is not SQL API, you will need to use the SDK specific for a particular API of Cosmod DB account.

Comment: It's probably straightforward, but I'm new to this. How can I check that? I don't have access to the cosmos db account, only a connection string to the database.

Comment: You can check this information on Azure Portal if you’ve access to it. Otherwise ask someone who has access to the Azure Portal.

Comment: Yes, it is table api. I'm trying to use the cosmosdb.table then, the imported data does indeed look better, although it still creates a new column (etag) and some fields are shown as " azure.cosmosdb.table.models.EntityProperty" which is a pain in the ass

Comment: Please edit your question and include the new code. Or you can accept this answer and ask a new question.

Comment: @SergioGM Please let me know how did you get rid of these two columns etag and azure.cosmosdb.table.models.EntityProperty

Comment: @SanjanaSanju I don't remember the exact setup I used, but I ended up using the azure.cosmosdb.table.tableservice.TableService class. If I remember right, with the method query_entities the results where clean